# add / rename keys on object typescript

Tags: typescript

hello i would like to add keys to my object at the moment i have this:

**interface:**

```
export interface IConstraint {
  [key: string]: string;
}
export interface IErrorFormater {
  field: string;
  errors: IConstraint;
}
```

**function to format errors:**

```
export const formatErrors = (validationErrors: ValidationError[]): IErrorFormater[] => {
  let response: IErrorFormater[] = [];
  for (let error of validationErrors) {
    let field: string = error.property;
    var constraints: string[] = [];
    for (let constraint in error.constraints) {
      if (!error.constraints.hasOwnProperty(constraint)) {
        continue;
      }
      constraints.push(error.constraints[constraint])

    };
    // // console.log(property, errorMessage)
    console.log(constraints)
    response.push({ field, errors: constraints });
  }

  return response;
}
```

with this code i got this:

```
[
  {
    "field": "departament_name",
    "errors": [
      "O nome do departamento precisa ser do tipo String",
      "departament_name must be an UUID"
    ]
  }
]
```

but i want add key to my errors, like this:

```
 "errors": [
         "1": "O nome do departamento precisa ser do tipo String",
         "2": "departament_name must be an UUID"
        ]
```

but I can't imagine how to do that

Comment: If you want to this format, `errors` should be an object, not an array.

Comment: yes but i dont know how i can add keys can help me?

Comment: You can convert the array to an object using `reduce`, like this: `constraints.reduce((prev, next, index) => (prev[index] = next, prev), {})` https://jsbin.com/finuxov/edit?js,console